# Pair trading based on cointegration - equity line

Tags: trading, returns, cointegration, pairs-trading, equity-curve

I'm preparing a project at my Uni where I have to make a simple *pair trading* strategy using cointegration between two stocks.

I'm stuck on the equity line calculation. I have prepared opening and closing signals but still have to prepare a **plot of equity line** but I don't know how to calculate it.

There are some details:

-long position in undervalued stock and short in overvalued

-short selling allowed without boundaries, with the deposit of 100% of the short sell value

-when opening the position, we assume **equal shares** of short and long positions

-**open/close** signals are defined by the **close price**, positions are **opened/closed** by the next day **open price**

-**transaction fee** are **0,1%** of position value (at the open and the close)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that can be really sophisticated even using such nice tools as pandas.
But the basic idea is to find position enters & exits to derive cashflow.

Here is my code to derive all that stuff from generated signals (in my backtester signals are fractions of 2 stocks in portfolio for each moment). I hope I've found all bugs here, but no warranties.
*Total_invested* variable is used to calculate total number of shares in portfolio using only initial capital.

Actually, this code is part of my backtest engine that I'm gonna open-source in a few months. It also deals with spreads and fixed commissions, so you may skip this part. It will require adaptation to your conditions, but hope that helps!

Also take a look at [articles by Mike Halls-Moore](https://www.quantstart.com/articles). This site helped me a lot!

```
def get_portfolio(self, signals, prices):
    time_index = prices.index
    end = time_index[-1]
    # Assets prices
    x_prices = prices[self.sym1]
    y_prices = prices[self.sym2]
    # Assets weights in portfolio
    x_weights = signals.map(lambda sig:sig[self.sym1])
    y_weights = signals.map(lambda sig:sig[self.sym2])
    # Total number of invested shares
    total_invested = pd.Series(index = signals.index)
    # Need trade enters to calculate portfolio size
    enter_points = x_weights.diff().fillna(0)!=0
    # Index magic here:
    # We need to delete position exits, we suppose there are separate enters/exits
    enter_points[enter_points[enter_points].index[1::2]] = False
    # capital = w₁⋅total⋅p₁ + w₂⋅total⋅p₂ (cover position)
    total_invested[enter_points] = (self.initial_capital
        /(x_weights.abs()[enter_points]*x_prices[enter_points]
        + y_weights.abs()[enter_points]*y_prices[enter_points]))
    # Zero for right initial open and final close
    total_invested.iloc[0] = 0; total_invested.iloc[-1] = 0;
    total_invested.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
    # Positions rounded to lot sizes
    x_positions = (total_invested*x_weights//self.lot1*self.lot1).fillna(0)
    y_positions = (total_invested*y_weights//self.lot2*self.lot2).fillna(0)
    long_pos = x_positions.copy(); long_pos[long_pos<0] = 0
    short_pos = x_positions.copy(); short_pos[short_pos>0] = 0
    x_pos_diff = x_positions.diff().fillna(0)
    y_pos_diff = y_positions.diff().fillna(0)

    # Tribute to the market-makers: spread
    # Binary divide because we count twice: enter & exit
    tribute = (abs(x_pos_diff)*self.spread1 + abs(y_pos_diff)*self.spread2)/2
    # Cashflow & Turnover: not the same!
    cashflow = -x_pos_diff*x_prices - y_pos_diff*y_prices
    turnover = abs(x_pos_diff)*x_prices + abs(y_pos_diff)*y_prices
    # Commission from turnover
    commission = turnover * self.commission
    commission[cashflow!=0] += self.fixed_commission
    portfolio = pd.DataFrame(index=time_index, columns=['EQ','holdings',
        'cash','cashflow','long_trades','short_trades',
        'x_positions','y_positions'])
    # Value of shares
    portfolio['holdings'] = x_positions*x_prices + y_positions*y_prices
    # Value of cash, paid commission on each transaction
    portfolio['cash'] = self.initial_capital + (cashflow
        - commission - tribute).cumsum()
    # Equity is the sum of both
    portfolio['EQ'] = portfolio['cash'] + portfolio['holdings']
    portfolio['turnover'] = turnover

    # Time points of trades
    portfolio['long_trades'] = long_pos.diff().fillna(0)
    portfolio['short_trades'] = short_pos.diff().fillna(0)

    portfolio['x_positions'] = x_positions
    portfolio['y_positions'] = y_positions
    return portfolio
```